# How to differentiate popup ,alert and new window in selenium?

Tags: selenium

If a new window is open, how will we find out whether the new window is alert or popup or window?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the control to pop-up window before doing any operations in it. By using this you can solve your problem.

```
Before opening the popup window get the handle of main window and save it.

String mwh=driver.getWindowHandle();

Now try to open the popup window by performing some action:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

Set s=driver.getWindowHandles(); //this method will gives you the handles of all opened windows

Iterator ite=s.iterator();

while(ite.hasNext())
{
    String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(mwh))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        /**/here you can perform operation in pop-up window**
        //After finished your operation in pop-up just select the main window again
        driver.switchTo().window(mwh);
    }
}
```